# Move contents of versioned S3 bucket with CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I moved the contents of multiple versioned buckets to a single versioned bucket with the following command: `aws s3 mv "s3://$OLD_BUCKET" "s3://$NEW_BUCKET/$OLD_BUCKET" --recursive`.

When I checked the new bucket, only the latest version of objects were there. I assume that it's possible to [copy objects including versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108158/copy-s3-bucket-including-versions) with `aws s3api copy-object ...`.  How do I **move** the versions that were left behind into the new bucket without them becoming the "latest" version in the new bucket?

Comment: This post has the same question but there's a solution posted using powershell that has a few up votes https://serverfault.com/a/935418/533532.
Would be be nice getting a linux version but that might help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can "move" old versions to "new" old versions.

Rather, you would need to **iterate through each previous version** (oldest first) and copy them to the destination. As each version gets overwritten by the newer version, they would become the "old" version. However, they would have different version IDs and the dates would be different.

I think that using Same Region Replication would preserve the versions as-is, but only for objects created *after* replication has been activated. You can use it to replicate existing objects